# How to split Partition External SD card for adoptable & Portable without rooting?

Tags: sd-card, partitions, app2sd, internal-sd, link2sd

My mobile device  have

> OS Android 6.0.1  Marshellow Processor Qualcomm Family cortex a53
> Machine arrch 64 Architecture arm cortex a53 External memory card 64GB
> ROM 16 GB MOBILE NOT ROOTED

It have option to formatting external card as internal but when I install user apps and move not all apps move to the internal formatted external as card some installs still on internal card. And occupies internal memory.

I tried to partition Micro SD card  from PC mini partition wizard and  created two three partition

first one of 20GB Fat32
Second one  20GB ext2
Third one  20 GB ext2.

When I connected it to mobile it doesn't show any partition and asked.for.formatting in portable or internal when I said  to format as internal it formatted and deleted all partitions.

After searching googling  founded  some posts and answers  in many forums and found the commands for and shell or terminal all emulator

```
adb shell sm list-disks adoptable
sm partition disk:179:160 mixed 25
adb shell sm format private:179,3
adb shell sm mount private:179,3
adb shell pm set-install-location 2
adb shell pm get-install-location
```

But will these commands for partitioning 2 portions and I want 3 dedicated  partitions

1. First fat32 one mountable viewable  for photos videos of fat32 partion readable in Windows to
2. Second ext2 one as apps moving ext2 partition for fast apps functioning
3. Third ext2 For backup of stock from or custom ROM a can't support more than 4gb file size

I tried these commands from Windows adb shell but  'SM' file not found error come

**Now my queries are :-**

1. Do SM & PM: command solve my problem to dedicated partitions for proper functioning. Of adoptable storage. In my case of Android 6.0.1
2. Does the SM  & PM commands needs to be  turned in terminal emulator or Windows DOS and shell
3. Does SM & PM command compatible in Android 6.01 do it function in it or not
4. Does SM & PM  command need rooting the mobile first
5. Does super user command SU should be running before SM & PM command but sinus not functioning to do SU function without rooting.
6. Where  to get binAry files SM & PM  & SU commands and how can we infuse or download in mobile system folder or can work without infusing in mobile by running bootloader recovery tarp image can we run it .... command help please
7. How to mount and view browwse ext2 external partions in Android as whenever I format it in ext2 it's unreadable  from file manager  or any app which app or command we can view or mount the ext2 partitions from Android mobile

As I am novice and new to Android adb commands Linux  commands to. So I need advice help to modify the command and precious advice. Kindly guide step by step?

Comment: never did but maybe clone small MicroSD Card (which is already mixed 50) to larger MicroSD Card with more disk space. finally add 3rd partition with external tool on remaining disk space

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without root but the method is much simpler out of necessity since in my experience, there are some exceptions but you did research and found the closest solution. I used the sm mixed partition method. You need to find a legitimate guide to it.
It is extremely important what order you do things in.
Also, you will have 3 storage partitions technically, an emulated sd that adopts the first partition, after performing the mixed partitioning, eject and safely remove sd card, -or what I would try is to leave unallocated space unpartitioned and then do the mixed partitioning. Then, these steps you should really google a confirmed working guide there are many with the wrong order of operations but it goes, format mixed safely remove and eject.
Power off android, insert sd card boot, allow it to adopt the sd card as fused storage increasing your emulated sd card. it's been so long since I did it so please do google I am very fuzzy on some details.
But I will say it was kinda unreliable for me, for a while my apps would be there, then .asked would disappear or suddenly my apps would be missing, as well and no real explanation.
And then I'd have to install it all again.
Also, apps that want to be on internal will move back after an update or reboot if I recall from my experience. And then you need to move them again.
The way I have been getting around that has been root. Although it's possible you can find a rootless solution that has the functionality of apktool m which lets you edit the apk of an app that will not allow itself to move to sd card you can quick edit that and set the apks preferred installation as auto, internal or external preferred.

If you can edit apks rootlessly then set external preferred and voila it now will allow move to sd card.
Do not do this with google apps. Globally setting external as your default installation medium doesn't work right? That's a deprecated thing from KitKat or am I wrong?

Anyway I would try it that way, also, you can use rikka's shizuku to allow sai to work rootlessly, and then you can try it's option that let's you choose.default installation media but I don't think it will work

But I was on 7,8 and 9 and was lacking so much knowledge  Which is ext 4 right? Now, reboot, and this time the other portable storage partition has to be set up as your extsd or media_rw partition and it'll be a fat or vfat partition. Not sure if you can mount or bind folders without root but that's another thing to look into.
And finally, you may have tried to leave unallocated space unpartitioned and inactive now I would try to format that space however you prefer, if it's ntfs android may not bother with trying to get you to format it, or maybe ext 2 would do that no idea and you can mount it with paragon a total commander plugin and a standalone app.
That way it's kinda guaranteed to be available to you in documentsui and such when making your recovery.
I personally think you could just do that on the portable storage partition.
That's what I do and upload to drive is an option or even a secondary old small 16gb sd card would work if you dont need that partition available all the time.
Or if you need all of them at the same time for the process to work you could get a cheap old sd card reader.
Just for after something bad happens. I'm not sure what your method is so I might be making dumb assumptions.
Anyway too much typing my head hurts.
Good luck. And if you can root do it man and then you can be frustrated with app2sd like me lmao pretty much as equally unreliable as the rootless mixed partition method. But yeah, it's super imperative that you let android adopt and then create the portable storage partitions or it will keep saying it's corrupt and try to repair it and not see it.

Oh, su is not needed for sm command are you sure you are following a good guide like on xda. I don't remember using the pm command just the partitioning part Try solid explorer, try fx file manager, try paragon, or some other partiotn5 mounting tool. Those commands won't do the trick as far as I know. But again I may be very wrong since it's been so long. But setting partitions yourself with the pm command is not what I did and I never tried to set a preferred install Location and have it work. Okay so tired. Gotta go. my brain is failing me.